# Recover deleted file from linode VPS server with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, vps, linode

I have accidentally deleted files from my VPS server bought from Linode. It uses Ubuntu 12.04. How can I recover the files. I hadn't enabled backup for it.

Comment: NOTICE:  This question has been crossposted to another SE group!  Very bad!

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask from Linode if they have any backups.

Now, the next step for you is to start taking your own backups.

Comment: I have asked linode for backups. And there is no backup from my side for certain files.

Comment: Sorry, then you are out of luck. If you can get the whole disk image for your server (as in whole `/dev/sda` or so), you can run PhotoRec `http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec` against it and see if it can find the files.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer .... NO.  Remember backups are your responsibility and an important one at that.